# Determining the difference between error_reporting(0) and pre-pending @ in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, error-reporting

Having written a custom error handler for a PHP system I'm trying to figure out how to determine if the error reporting level (which can be obtained via [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)) has been globally set to Off (0) or has been disabled for that line only using the [@ prefix](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

The issue at current is that for both circumstances the error_reporting() function returns 0

**Update #1**

This example unfortunately does not work for PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.8 as the ini_get() function returns the same value as error_reporting()

```
function errhandle($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    if (error_reporting() === 0 && error_reporting() === (int)ini_get('error_reporting')) {
        echo 'error_reporting(0) was used';
    } else if (error_reporting() === 0 && error_reporting() !== (int)ini_get('error_reporting')) {
        echo '@ was used';
    }
}

set_error_handler('errhandle');

echo error_reporting()."\n";
echo @$arr['name'];

// Prints
22527
error_reporting(0) was used
```

Comment: I understand the use and purpose of it, however I'd like to keep that discussion out of the scope of this question. [dkellner's comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#119693) sums it up well

`There is no reason to NOT use something just because "it can be misused".  You could as well say "unlink is evil, you can delete files with it so don't ever use unlink".

It's a valid point that the @ operator hides all errors - so my rule of thumb is: use it only if you're aware of all possible errors your expression can throw AND you consider all of them irrelevant.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to `error_reporting()`, you can also check the error reporting level with `ini_get('error_reporting')`. Theoretically this is similar, but it has a subtle difference that makes it valuable for what you're trying to do.

If the error reporting has been disabled globally with `error_reporting(0)` then `ini_get('error_reporting')` will return the string `0`. But if error reporting was left alone and the line was prefixed with `@`, it will return a non-zero value (the value of the existing INI directive).

So you can compare the 2 values and determine exactly what happened:

```
if (error_reporting() === 0 && error_reporting() === (int)ini_get('error_reporting')) {
    echo 'error_reporting(0) was used';
} else if (error_reporting() === 0 && error_reporting() !== (int)ini_get('error_reporting')) {
    echo '@ was used';
}
```

This is just an example of the kind of condition you can do in your custom error handler. If it's not quite what you want, let me know and I'll try tweaking it.

<sup>Tested locally on my PHP 7.1.2 (CLI on Windows).</sup>

---

**Update #1**

After a bit more thought I came up with this idea. Just a warning, this seems very hacky and inefficient, but I'm starting to think it might be the only way to do it.

If you're following the example from the PHP docs for [set_error_handler](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), then the function signature for your custom error handler probably looks like this:

`function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)`

In other words, you have the file and line number where the error occurred. You can use this info to open the file itself, look at that line number, parse the tokens and look for the `@` character. The code would look like this:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    $errfileContents = file($errfile);
    $errlineContents = $errfileContents[$errline - 1];
    $tokens = token_get_all('<?php ' . $errlineContents . ' ?>');
    if (error_reporting() === 0) {
        if (in_array('@', $tokens)){
            echo '@ was used';
        } else {
            echo 'error_reporting(0) was used';
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you could expand that condition by checking to see if both or neither of the techniques were used.

Anyway, it's ugly, but it's working for me on my PHP 5.6.6 (CLI on Windows).

Comment: I gave a similar method a shot before posting the question. Having copied your exact code, this doesn't work for PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.8 - Updated the main question with code snippet

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting it doesn't work on the older PHP version... does your app have any kind of initialization phase that always runs first? Maybe you can check the error reporting level at the very beginning of the script and save it in a global variable, then you can check it later in the error handler function to see if it changed. I will brainstorm about other solutions, but that's the first alternative that comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah, it's an interesting problem. For my particular application it's possible that I could log the level before hand, but I'm hoping that there may be another solution that doesn't require this step to make the error handler more universal. If ini_get() had of worked, it would have been perfect!

Comment: After a bit more testing I found that with PHP 5.6.23 on CentOS 6.9 the solution also failed, but PHP 7.0.23 on Fedora 25 worked

Comment: I'm starting to think there's no quick or easy way to do this, but I did think of one potential solution. If you're _really_ set on doing this, see the updated section of my answer.

Comment: I think the only limitation with your updated idea is going to be if multiple statements are present on a single line. However, I think it's a case of accepting that there is no "nice" or "proper" way of handling this on any version below PHP 7. Since your first response works perfectly on PHP 7 I've marked it as accepted, thanks again